# google sheets dropdown with customized output

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on google sheets trying to implement a customized dropdown as follows:

cells in sheet1!A7:A26 should contain the dropdown menu.
the dropdown data is in cells supportSheet!C3:C12. for example "I - category 1", "II - category 2", and so on.
So the normal dropdown would put the chosen data into the cell. What I would like to have is only the roman numeral e.g. "II" put into the cell.
I obviously could do a dropdown with only the roman numerals to choose from but when choosing the categories I would like to see all category names displayed in the dropdown so I would know which roman numeral is which category.
Basically, the input should be any kind of displaying the categories including the roman numerals and output only the roman numeral into the output cell.

I hope I could give all needed information to my problem. If not, please ask for more and will try to provide.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the cell you want the dynamic drop down in.
2. From the menu select Data - > Data Validation.
3. From the Data Validation display select Drop Down From Range
4. Set the data range you want for the drop down (in this case C3:C12 from sheet supportSheet.
5. Click Done

The original selected cell will now have a drop down with items from the selected range.